# AngularJS KendoUI DatePicker Model not binding

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, datepicker

i want to bind the Today date to the model and  to the Kendo UI Datepicker and keep them in sync but it doesn't work... my DatePicker never show the model value on the control.

here is my code Angular:

```
vm.startDateOptions = {
    parseFormats: ["YYYY-MM-DD"]
};

vm.searchInfos = {
    startDate: moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-M-D') 
    // Giving 2015-10-14 for today
}
```

Html :

```
<input onkeydown="return false;" id="start" kendo-date-picker 
    k-options="vm.startDateOptions"
    k-ng-model="vm.searchInfos.start" 
    style="width: 100%;"  />
```

Comment: Maybe you've made a mistake here `k-ng-model="vm.searchInfos.start"`. 
You should use `startDate` instead of `start`.

Comment: arg.... so many time to try to understand the problem for a mistake like that.... thx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use values to display it in your html you can use something like this

```
<h4>Select date:</h4>
        <input 
         kendo-date-time-picker
         k-options="monthSelectorOptions"             
         data-k-ng-model="dateObject"
         data-ng-model="dateString.startDate" 
         style="width: 100%;" />

var startDate = new Date();

      $scope.monthSelectorOptions = {
        value: startDate,
        startDate: startDate,
        format: "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt",
        parseFormats: ['ddd MMM dd yyyy'],
        animation: {
            close: {
                effects: "fadeOut zoom:out",
                duration: 300
            },
            open: {
                effects: "fadeIn zoom:in",
                duration: 300
            }
        },
        culture: "de-DE",
      };
```

[And here is complete solution](http://dojo.telerik.com/aXEfI/9)